# Exc_bad_access Error in fscanf

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode5

I'm running the following code in Xcode setup for iOS project and get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address 0x30) on the second `fscanf` command i.e. `fscanf(fid, "%d", &fIndex);` in the first iteration itself i.e. with `j = 0`;

```
char word[wordLength]; // wordlength is set to 4
int numFiles = 0;
int fIndex = 0;
// create the word-fileIndex mapping
for(long i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
{
    fscanf(fid, "%s%d", word, &numFiles);
    vector<int> indexList(numFiles,0);
    for(int j = 0; j < numFiles; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fid, "%d", &fIndex);
        indexList[j] = fIndex;
    }
    wordIndexMap[word] = indexList;
}
```

However, just for the sake of testing, I added another value to be scanned in the first `fscanf` like this:

```
fscanf(fid, "%s%d%d", word, &numFiles, &fIndex);
```

And it ran fine and read the correct value from the file.

Can someone enlighten me with what is going on here?

My input file is like this:

> abcd num_Index index1 index2 ....

e.g.

```
1234 2 14 15
1235 3 5 2 6
1111 1 1
```

Comment: This looks like C++, which therefore is *not* Objective-C *or* C.

Comment: `fscanf` is part of C library and I've added Objective-C just in case if something of this sort is specific to language + Xcode combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set `wordLength` to more than 4 because you need to include the trailing `'\0'`. In any case, you need to be careful when reading input like that and limit how many characters you're reading.

Comment: Agreed; `%4s` should be used.  Not sure it's the cause of the OPs problems though.

Comment: As I had mentioned in the question, the error is not in reading the first word which is of wordlength=4, the first fscanf works correct, its the second one which is reading the list of indexes is giving the error

Comment: @Ani You have failed to realise the implications of "A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence" means to your code.  See the `fscanf()` manpage.  Anyway stop using that rubbish and simply use `<<` to read your strings and numbers.

Comment: Something I learned a long time ago is that if I find a bug while looking for another, I should fix it first :) In this case... it may be related, as you're overflowing the word variable. Anyway, I couldn't find anything else that's wrong. Sorry.

Comment: I was aware of `\0` but since the word was being read fine... I didn't considered that as an issue. Using `%4s` didn't help but increasing wordlength to 10 did the trick. Thnx!

Comment: Cool. Just to make things clear - to read a 4 letter word, you need at least a 5 character array because of the trailing `'\0'` that is added. That's why `%4s` didn't help. It's still a good idea to limit how much you're reading - use `%4s` if you only expect 4 letters.

Comment: @trojanfoe could you give an example for using `<<` to read strings and numbers from file?

Comment: Something like `ifstream f = ...; f >> word >> numfiles; for (...) { f >> fIndex; }`.  You need to add error checking tho.

Comment: @trojanfoe started a private chat room to discuss related question http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40261/room-for-ani-and-trojanfoe